# Powershell select-string fails due to escape sequence

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having a file which has following contents

```
change sets:
  promotion level: INITIAL
  depends on: 
    GEESF_R2.1.0.9.5179@\My_PVOB (MES@\My_PVOB)
    My_2.1.0.13.4875@\My_PVOB (Notification@\My_PVOB)
    MyComponents_8_8_2011.6859@\My_PVOB (SQLReporting@\My_PVOB)
    My_2.1.0.13.7098@\My_PVOB (Support@\My_PVOB)
```

I wanted to read the contents which has pattern @\My_PVOB)

So i write select-string option like this.

```
Select-string -pattern "@\My_PVOB)" -path "C:\Baselines.txt"
```

But i am getting following issue

```
parsing "@\My_PVOB)" - Unrecognized escape sequence \M.
```

Even if change the pattern as

```
Select-string -pattern "@\\My_PVOB)" -path "c:\Baselines.txt"
```

I am getting following error

```
 "@\\My_PVOB)" - Too many )'s.
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The round bracket is a special character, so you should escape it:

```
Select-string -pattern "@\\My_PVOB\)" -path "c:\Baselines.txt"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Escape method to replace metacharacters with their escape codes:

```
PS> $pattern = [regex]::Escape('@\My_PVOB)')
PS> $pattern
@\\My_PVOB\)

PS> Select-String -Path c:\Baselines.txt -Pattern $pattern
```

Comment: Or use `-SimpleMatch` to avoid regex evaluation altogether.