# Unable to match pattern when string exists in file

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

I'm trying to find a line that matches the below pattern in a file. I can see the pattern is output as I expect but it doesn't match.

**String in file**

```
"5/29/2019 12:01:03 PM - Sys - Logged Successfully"
```

**Variables**

```
$pattern = "Logged Successfully"
$datePattern = "5/29/2019"
```

**Code - Working - Matches ok**

```
$reponse = select-string -Path $path\$file -Pattern $pattern -allmatches -simplematch
```

**Code - Not Working**

```
$reponse = select-string -Path $path\$file -Pattern "$($datePattern).*$($pattern)" -allmatches -simplematch
```

Maybe im missing something very simple, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove `-SimpleMatch` from your second code sample. That parameter causes `Select-String` to do string comparisons, whereas you want a regular expression match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matches not captured when using -SimpleMatch with Select-String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179734/matches-not-captured-when-using-simplematch-with-select-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the **-simplematch** switch from the code sample that is not working and then it will work. You are *disabling* a regular expression match while using that switch. See [this previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179734/matches-not-captured-when-using-simplematch-with-select-string) from Mathias R. Jessen where he explains in more detail.