# Select-String: match a string only if it isn't preceded by * character

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string, negative-lookbehind

I have this line in a Powershell script:

`if (Select-String -Path "$holidays" -Pattern "(?<!\*)$datestr" -SimpleMatch -Quiet)`

$holidays is a text file where i have some date:

```
2023-09-04
2023-11-23
*2023-11-24
2023-12-25
```

$datestr is today date: 2023-11-23

why negative lookbehind pattern doesn't work in the line above?

I just want to esclude (don't match) all dates that start with *

I think that something is wrong in negative lookbehind because the line:

```
if (Select-String -Path "$holidays" -Pattern $datestr -SimpleMatch -Quiet)
```

works perfectly --> results is true

in the first line results is false

Comment: Because `-SimpleMatch` doesn't use regex :) or, if it does use the regex class, it first escapes the pattern to get a literal match

Comment: Just try `... |  where-object {$_ -notmatch [regex]::Escape('*')}` and see if that gets it done.

Comment: While conceptually related, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33179734/45375 is _not_ a duplicate of this question: the latter is about _deliberate_ use of `-SimpleMatch` (and the subsequent unavailability of matching information via the output objects' `.Matches` property).

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, just a heads up: this question was just - in my estimation - inappropriately closed as a duplicate (I reopened it; see my previous comment). However, the alleged duplicate implicitly answers the question in your first comment: No, (escaped) regex matching is _not_ employed with `-SimpleMatch`, as evidenced by the fact that the `.Matches` property is then not populated in the output objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in comments, when [`-SimpleMatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3#-simplematch) is used the cmdlet doesn't use [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.4):

> Indicates that the cmdlet uses a simple match rather than a regular expression match. In a simple match, `Select-String` searches the input for the text in the Pattern parameter. It doesn't interpret the value of the Pattern parameter as a regular expression statement.

In your case the cmdlet is looking for a literal `(?<!\*)2023-11-23` instead of **`2023-11-23` not preceded by `*`**:

```bash
$datestr = '2023-11-23'
'2023-11-23' | Select-String -Pattern "(?<!\*)$datestr" -SimpleMatch -Quiet # No output
'2023-11-23' | Select-String -Pattern "(?<!\*)$datestr" -Quiet              # True
```

In summary, your condition should be:

```bash
if (Select-String -Path $holidays -Pattern "(?<!\*)$datestr" -Quiet) {
    # do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Let me complement **[Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77539642/45375)** with some **background information**:

- [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) interprets its **`-Pattern`** argument(s) as [regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) *by default*.
- It is only if you want *literal* substring matching that you need **`-SimpleMatch`**.
- In either case, matching is case-*insensitive* by default (as PowerShell generally is); use
  **`-CaseSensitive`** as needed.
- `-SimpleMatch` is not be confused with these **other switches** - which are unrelated to whether `-Pattern` arguments are interpreted as regexes or literal strings:

  - **`-Raw`** - available in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only - emits matching input strings (lines) *as-is* instead of the default behavior of reporting them wrapped in [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances, which supplement a matching input string with *metadata* about the match.
  - **`-AllMatches`** (incompatible with `-Raw` and `-SimpleMatch`) requests that, on *each input string (line)*, *all* matches for the pattern(s) be looked for instead of just the *first*.

    - Note: `-Raw` emits *strings* only, so by definition no information about *which parts of each string matched* can be reported; similarly, `-SimpleMatch` records no such information, even though with *multiple* `-Pattern` arguments it may be of interest; also, unfortunately, as of v7.4.0, combining `-SimpleMatch` with `-AllMatches` is *quietly accepted*, even though `-AllMatches` then has *no effect* - see [GitHub issue #11091](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11091)
    - The [`.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo.Matches) property of `MatchInfo` objects is a *collection* of [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) objects precisely in order to support `-AllMatches`. Without the latter, the `.Matches` collection only ever has *one* entry.
  - **`-List`** stops processing further input strings once a string with match(es) is found, and outputs a `MatchInfo` instance (or a `[string]` instance with `-Raw`) *only for that input*, i.e. at most *one* per input file - this can be an important performance improvement.
  - **`-Quiet`** acts like `-List`, except that instead of emitting a `MatchInfo` instance it emits `$true`, i.e. an *abstract indicator* that a match was found.

    - Note: While it stands to reason that `$false` would be emitted if *no* matches are found, this is *not* the case as of PowerShell (Core) 7.4.0; instead, there is *no output*; see [GitHub issue#16681](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16681).
      That said, in an implied Boolean context, *no output* is tantamount to `$false` - see the conceptual [about_Booleans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Booleans) help topic

Comment: Wow, you're **R E A L L Y** going an extra mile just to make sure a question is answered conclusively and comprehensively.   You should get paid by MSFT.  